# Generating a truly random string in PHP

Tags: php, random

I need to generate thousands (possibly millions) of unique codes for a client. These codes may have a monetary value, so it's vital that they are TRULY random, and that no pattern could be spotted and exploited by a clever hacker.

I've looked at various solutions for generating the code (cyclically generated = could be guessed, too risky, `uniqid()` = good, but I may need a code of a different length).

Right now I'm thinking of generating the code using A-Z and 0-9 MINUS VOWELS (in order to ensure no rude words could be accidentally generated) although this may be increased in the future to lowercase characters, etc.

So far I have this:

Edit: Per @kingero's comment, below, I've upped the randomness ante in a solution replacing `mt_rand` with a custom rand function taken from [here](http://codeascraft.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/):

```
function generateCode($length = 12) {
    $chars = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ0123456789';
    $count = mb_strlen($chars);

    for ($i = 0, $result = ''; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomIndex = devurandom_rand(0, $count - 1);
        $result .= mb_substr($chars, $randomIndex, 1);
    }

    return $result;
}

// CUSTOM RAND FUNCTION
// equiv to rand, mt_rand
// returns int in *closed* interval [$min,$max]                                                
function devurandom_rand($min = 0, $max = 0x7FFFFFFF) {
    $diff = $max - $min;
    if ($diff < 0 || $diff > 0x7FFFFFFF) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Bad range");
    }
    $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    if ($bytes === false || strlen($bytes) != 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get 4 bytes");
    }
    $ary = unpack("Nint", $bytes);
    $val = $ary['int'] & 0x7FFFFFFF;   // 32-bit safe                           
    $fp = (float) $val / 2147483647.0; // convert to [0,1]                          
    return round($fp * $diff) + $min;
}
```

It's pretty basic, so I'm obviously concerned that it's not random enough. Can anyone tell me if this a decent way to ensure that the generated code is truly random?

(Note: Obviously a wannabe hacker will always be able to attempt a brute force attack. Such attempts will be handled elsewhere, I just want to make sure this code is truly random.)

Comment: From the manual on `mt_rand()`: "Caution
This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead." - If you are ok with `uniqid()` but need a different length, why don't you just concatenate/cut?

Comment: @kingkero The client may need more possible combinations in fewer chars (e.g. six chars), so `uniqid()` may be not be good for that reason.

Comment: @kingero You're right that I shouldn't have been using mt_rand() -- thanks!

Comment: `to ensure no rude words could be accidentally generated` That's funny.. you really taking care!. Imagine: Your code is: `penis2` (chuckle)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following implementation and I hope to be useful for you:

```
function createRandStr($length, $spChars = false){
        $alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstwvxyz';
        $alphaUp = strtoupper($alpha);
        $num = '12345678901234567890';
        $sp = '@/+.*-\$#!)[';
        $thread = $alpha.$alphaUp.$num;
        if ($spChars) $thread .= $sp;
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
            $str .= $thread[mt_rand(0, strlen($thread)-1)];
        }
        return $str;

    }
```

Checkout this live DEMO: http://codepad.org/QnvP7fFl